# LINQ to XML XDocument changes DOCTYPE on save

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some xml with following DOCTYPE declaration at the beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE setup SYSTEM "setup.dtd">
```

My code processes the xml more or less like that:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
doc.Element("foo")
             .Element("bar")
             .Elements()
             .Attributes()
             .Where(x => x.Name == "some" && x.Value == some)
             .Single()
             .Parent
             .SetValue(newValue);
doc.Save(path);
```

The code changes value of some xml node inside its structure. Surprisingly it affects also DOCTYPE and after the operation it looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE setup SYSTEM "setup.dtd"[]>
```

Why it does so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `InternalSubset` property of the `DocumentType` is set to an empty string.  When this is passed to the underlying `XmlWriter.WriteDocType` method it adds an empty collection of internal subset declarations.

This is still valid, though you can prevent this by setting  the `InternalSubset` value to `null`:

```
doc.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null;
doc.Save(path);
```